# Query result different from query made into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I made a query to populate my table and converted it into a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getSAPCMTX]

@sSDate varchar(10), 
@sEDate varchar(10), 
@sBranch varchar(4000)

AS

DELETE FROM SAPCMTX 
WHERE DocDate BETWEEN @sSDate AND @sEDate AND
StoreCode IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@sBranch , ',')) 

INSERT INTO SAPCMTX
SELECT * FROM Table T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN @sSDate AND @sEDate AND T0.DataSource<>'O' AND 
  T1.TreeType<>'I' AND T0.DocType = 'I' AND 
  StoreCode IN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (SELECT Item FROM
  dbo.SplitStrings(@sBranch , ',')) 
GO
```

To run it I used this command

```
EXEC    [dbo].[sp_getSAPCMTX]
        @sSDate = '3/8/2016',
        @sEDate = '3/8/2016',
        @sBranch = '002'
```

It returns 33 rows but when I try to run it separately as a TSQL it returns 34 row.

```
DECLARE @sSDate varchar(10)
DECLARE @sEDate varchar(10) 
DECLARE @sBranch varchar(4000)

SET @sSDate = '3/8/2016'
SET @sEDate = '3/8/2016'
SET @sBranch = '002'


DELETE FROM SAPCMTX 
WHERE DocDate BETWEEN @sSDate AND @sEDate AND
StoreCode IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings(@sBranch , ',')) 

INSERT INTO SAPCMTX
SELECT * FROM Table T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN @sSDate AND @sEDate AND T0.DataSource<>'O' AND 
  T1.TreeType<>'I' AND T0.DocType = 'I' AND 
  StoreCode IN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (SELECT Item FROM
  dbo.SplitStrings(@sBranch , ',')) 
GO
```

Any idea why there is a difference in the result considering it is essentially the same query?

Comment: Well - take a look at the extra row you get back - then you can easier debug why and what.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two possibilities that could help you getting the desired results:

- [`SET ANSI_NULLS ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(v=SQL.80).aspx) before altering the procedure:

  ```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getSAPCMTX]
      -- your code of the procedure
  ```
- Create local properties and copy the value of the parameters into them:

  ```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getSAPCMTX]
      @sSDate VARCHAR(10)
      @sEDate VARCHAR(10)
      @sBranch VARCHAR(4000)
  AS
  DECLARE @sDate VARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @eDate VARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @branch VARCHAR(4000)

  SET @sDate = @sSDate
  SET @eDate = @sEDate
  SET @branch = @sBranch

  -- your code of the procedure
  ```

Comment: I tried the first one still the same
For the second one, that's what I did just to get the desired result but I'm still wondering why do I need to create local variables to get correct output